# Java serialization and deserialization on different API levels

Tags: java, android, serialization

I want to store object in file with every sub-object it contains. At first I wanted to use JAXB, but it takes 9MB of disk space - due to my app limited disk space requirement I can not take much of disk space. Thus I thought about serialization and here is my question.

Does different Java versions support the same serialization algorithms?

If I wanted to serialize my object in Java 1.8 would I still be able to deserialize it with Java 1.2 without any problems or data losses?

Of course I am using object validation, app will be running of devices with API 15 to API 21.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather use Gson ?  (or jackson)

Comment: Thanks, seems like it is perfect replacement for standard serialization.

Comment: Trust me it is. it makes life much more easy.. I'm also writing this as an answer since I feel you accepted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you don't bother with Java serialization and switch to Gson (or jackson) unless you have a good reason to avoid them